# mock.verify() doesn't fail the test - if called from Promise callback

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, sinon

This question is very similar to the one which is here: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/2138

I'll use the same example:

```
it("test case 100", () => {
    return getPromiseA().then((A1) => {
        const mock1 = sinon.mock(MyObject);
        mock1.expects("someMethod").twice();
        A1.getPromiseB("1234").then((response) => {
            mock1.restore();
            mock1.verify();
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("+++--- (Error) END of testCase +++++");
        }
    }, (rejectedP) => {
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("-------- (REJ-C) END of testCase ++++");
    });
});
```

The line of code: `mock1.expects("someMethod").twice();` should fail when `mock1.verify();`
is called.
Under normal circumstances, `mock1.verify();` will throw an exception and the test case will fail.

But in the above example, the test case doesn't fail.
An error is posted in the browser console - that's it.

The fix for this would be that the test case SHOULD fail.
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know much about Sinon, but generally speaking, async things will cause the test to finish before the async functionality has been resolved, which is your problem here. Maybe this page can help?: https://sinonjs.org/how-to/lolex-async-promises/

Answer (score 0):

Got it, it can get a bit confusing when using chained promises. Here's what can be done:

```
it("test case 100", () => {
    let mock1 = null;
    return getPromiseA().then((A1) => {
        mock1 = sinon.mock(MyObject);
        mock1.expects("someMethod").twice();
        return A1.getPromiseB("1234");
    }).then(() => {
        // response from "A1.getPromiseB"
        mock1.restore();
        mock1.verify();
    });
// No need for catch, since the error will be caught and reported as failure by Sinon.
});
```

This solved the issue that I was facing.